# How can add space in this plot ? I am a beginner in R

Tags: r, plot, par

Here is the code for plotting 10 different graphs

```
lab=unique(train_train$PdDistrict)
lab=as.character(lab)
par(mfrow=c(5,2))

for(i in 1:length(lab))
{
  a=plot(table(train_train[train_train$PdDistrict==lab[i],1]),las=3,main=lab[i])
}
```

The resultant graph is shown in this image link

[image]

How can i space those graphs so that its readable ?

Comment: send it to another device like a pdf: `pdf('file.pdf'); ## plot code here; dev.off()` where you can adjust the height and width to be whatever you need. or use fewer panels per page, eg `mfrow = c(2,2)` or something

Comment: Read `?par` and look for `'mar'`. However, with the complexity of your graphs' x-axis labels, @rawr's note will still be (or even more so) applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My new code that I modified

```
lab=unique(train_train$PdDistrict)
lab=as.character(lab)
par(mfrow=c(1,2),mar=c(9,4,1,0))

for(i in 1:length(lab))
{

  a=plot(table(train_train[train_train$PdDistrict==lab[i],1]),las=2,main=lab[i])
}
```

[image]

Now it looks much better.